# Abort() has been called - Connect Function multithreads Cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, bittorrent

I am trying to use multithread for connecting for more then one peer simultinaly.
While I am running my code and run more then a one thread the program crashes in the "connect" function and it writes: "Abort() has been called".

This is How I call to the threads:

```
TcpPeers(OrderedMap<std::string, unsigned short> peers, std::string     infoHash)
   {
    this->peers = peers;
    peersArr = new Peer[peers.GetSize()];

    for (int i = 0; i < peers.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        Peer * pp = new Peer(peers.GetKeyByIndex(i), peers.GetValueByIndex(i), infoHash);
        *(peersArr + i) = *pp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < peers.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        std::thread t1(&Peer::CreateConnection, *(peersArr + i));
    }
}
```

A peer is another client that I need to connect with while I am trying to implement the bittorent protocol.

Again, when there is one thread all goes right, when I have more then two peers all crashes.

Comment: What is `peers` and what is `peersArr`. Are you sure that `peers.GetSize()` is not bigger than size of `peersArr`. Please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited my questoion :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a `std::thread` object gets destroyed it is not allowed to be `joinable()`, i.e., one of two things have to happen before it is destroyed:

1. It was detached and the thread has gone into the wild and there is pretty much no control over whether it has finished or not.
2. The thread has been `join()`ed.

If a `std::thread` object is destroyed without either of these states, `std::terminate()` is called which is probably the cause for the call to `abort()` you observe. In your loop you keep destroying threads without having called either `detach()` or `join()` on them. The system sees that as a request to terminate your program.

In case you need a reference for this behavior: see 30.3.1.3 [thread.thread.destr] paragraph 1:

> `~thread();`
>
> If `joinable()`, calls `std::terminate()`. Otherwise, has no effects. [ Note: Either implicitly detaching or joining a `joinable()` thread in its destructor could result in difficult to debug correctness (for `detach`) or performance (for `join`) bugs encountered only when an exception is raised. Thus the programmer must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still `joinable`. —end note ]

Comment: Thanks! But what can I do in case I want my program to continue runnig (for example for gui) Should I create a thread inside a thread inside a thread? Is it a good solution?

Comment: @YoavFranco: most likely you'd keep your `std::thread` objects around, e.g., in a `std::vector<std::thread>` or with a bit of additional information in a suitable location. This way you could also have a thread cleaning up threads meant to be terminated (i.e., `join()`ing them). How exactly that's done depends on the structure of your program.

Comment: @dietmar-kuehl thank you, storing my threads in a `std::vector<std::thread>` and joining them one-by-one by looping through the vector once I want to terminate (e.g. at the end of main) is exactly what I am doing now.